# Lots of sites timing out and strange IP request

Tags: router, windows-8.1, dns

I have been having website / DNS issues in the last 12 hours only. Sites are timing out or response times are slow. It sometimes takes a few attempts to get even a small page. This occurs not just in a browser, but also with a site scraper I've written.

In this scraper, it failed with the message that a connection to `198.18.1.88:443` timed out. This is strange as this IP is reserved and private and there would be no links to it at all. This has led to to think malware.

I've done a speedtest, and things seem fine, I've looked at DNS config with an `ipconfig /all` which shows that the DNS server is an `192.168.1.x` address. My ISP has not reported any issues neither.

What else can I look for to diagnose / fix?

Comment: Have you tried changing DNS locally maybe? Have you tried restarting your router? It seems that you don't have access to internet so your router instead redirects all connections to its web GUI.

Comment: I haven't tried a different DNS provider, I haven't restarted router. I don't understand why there would be a strange request to 198.18.x.x though when I know for sure that no original outbound request to that address was made..

Comment: Because your request was redirected.

Comment: But what would cause that redirect? malware?

Comment: I would say it's unlikely to be malware, because it was redirected to local LAN. Your router and/or Windows.

Comment: Please don't assume malware when there is a perfectly reasonable and common explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You are using your router as a DNS server. This is a common default configuration for routers. You will find that you can change the settings in the router so that it advertises different DNS settings for the DHCP clients.

Try changing your PC first to manually use a different DNS. Try Google or OpenDNS. If that works, try using your IPS's DNS directly. If that also works, your router is struggling to keep up, not uncommon on home routers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like DNS issues for me.
Try to proceed with following checks when this issue arises:

```
nslookup somewebsite.com
```

If you have a timeout or just command exec takes a long time, try to use google dns servers instead:

```
nslookup somewebsite.com 8.8.8.8
```

If this works, change your DNS server in the network settings to the 8.8.8.8

If DNS works, try to do traceroute to the same website and check if any lost packages in the transit, but most likely it's DNS.

You also may find more helpful info [here](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips) too.

Regards.